# Java - Skipping a line when reading user input into an array (for loop)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Here's my code - The objective is to enter some basic info (age, name, gender) for x number of patients.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int numPatients = 2;

    int[] age = new int[numPatients];
    String[] gender = new String[numPatients];
    String[] name = new String[numPatients];
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    /*
     * Obtaining patients details: name, gender, age
     * First create a Scanner input variable to read the data
     */
    for (int i = 0; i < numPatients; i++)
    {
    System.out.println("Enter name of patient " + (i+1));
     name[i] =  in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter gender (male/female) of patient " + (i+1));
     gender[i] =  in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter age of patient " + (i+1));
     age[i] =  in.nextInt();
    }
```

The issue I'm having is when the loop goes to the 2nd variable, i.e. I'm not able to enter a value for the name of the patient. It seems to skip taking the input there and goes directly to the next input, which is gender.

```
Enter name of patient 1
Mark
Enter gender (male/female) of patient 1
Male
Enter age of patient 1
34
Enter name of patient 2 //Skipped. Could not enter input here
Enter gender (male/female) of patient 2
Jenna
```

Any idea why that happens? Is it better to use BufferedReader instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you must use `Scanner`, then *always* use `nextLine()`. The problem is that `nextInt()` reads *only* the integer part of the input and stops before it reads the Enter keypress. Then the next call to `nextLine()` sees the Enter keypress in the buffer and things you entered an empty name.

So you can do something like:

```
age[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

and be prepared to handle the exception that will happen if the user types something other than a number.

Comment: Really interesting and I wouldn't have caught that. Thanks for the help, Greg. It works now!

Answer (score 0):

If you are assured that name will be a single word (not an issue for male or female)then you can modify the scanner input to just get the string;

```
   in.next();
```

this works fine (only if name's a single word ).